# How to take webpage screenshots using QWebEngineView without opening window

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebengineview

I'm looking for a way to take website screenshots with `QWebEngineView`.  The main goal is to develop a headless screencapture application that runs in the background.

I've managed to get a minimal working example to work (see [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/79816/qwebengineview-screenshot) for example).  However, these examples require that the `QWebEngineView` widget is made visible, either with calls to `QWebEngineView::show()`, `QWebEngineView::showMinimized()` or even `QWebEngineView::setVisible(true)`, to be able to take a screen capture of a website.  As this results in opening a series of windows, this solution is less than perfect.

Does anyone know of a way to use `QWebEngineView` to take screenshots of websites without having windows popping open?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is rather easy: configure the `QWebEngineView` widget to not show onscreen by setting the `Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen` attribute through a call to `QWidget::setAttribute(Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen)`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum