# QWebEngineView: Timers do not function when visible

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtimer, qwebengineview

I was attempting to implement the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55295666/how-to-capture-full-web-page-using-qtwebengine), but I have discovered that `QTimer` does not fire under certain circumstances.

The simplified code:

```
app = QApplication([])

view = QWebEngineView()
view.show()

def callback():
    sys.exit(0)

QTimer.singleShot(1000, callback)

app.exec()
```

The application runs forever with this code (ie. `callback` is never executed).  However, if you comment out `view.show()` then it exits after one second as it should.

As far as I can tell, this problem is particular to `QWebEngineView`; if we replace the `QWebEngineView` with a generic `QWidget` or `QLabel`, then it works as expected and exits after one second.

What is the cause of this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: How strange I have tested the code in Python 3.8.1, PyQt5 5.14.1 on Linux and it works correctly.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.2, the same pyqt version, and Windows 10.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, try other versions of pyqt5.

Comment: Where do you run your code: CMD or the interactive python console or some IDE?

Comment: I've tried PyCharm's IDE and the console; the problem exists in both.

Comment: mmm, I think it's a bug, try earlier versions of pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine. Are you using the same version of pyqt5 and pyqtwebengine?

Comment: You were right!  It appears to be a bug introduced sometime after version 5.12.1 of pyqtwebengine.  Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You better publish it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As prompted by @eyllanesc, I have discovered that this is a bug introduced by the 5.14.0 release of the `PyQtWebEngine` module; the previous version (5.13.2) does not show this behavior.